# php not interpreted into symfony2 project (Akeneo)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, symfony-2.1, akeneo

I am trying to install a new Symfony 2 project.
Everything is ok, only when I go to the home page, this appears (the php does not seem to be interpreted):

> unregister(); $apcLoader->register(true); */ require_once
>   **DIR**.'/../app/AppKernel.php'; //require_once **DIR**.'/../app/AppCache.php'; $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); $kernel->loadClassCache(); //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
>   $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response =
>   $kernel->handle($request); $response->send();
>   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

**When I do a**

```
composer require symfony/requirements-checker
```

*No mistake.*

**Only when I do a**

```
composer require doctrine/orm
```

*This error appears:*

> ```
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - akeneo/pim-community-dev v1.6.22 requires doctrine/orm 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.4.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     - akeneo/pim-community-dev v1.6.22 requires doctrine/orm 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.4.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     - akeneo/pim-community-dev v1.6.22 requires doctrine/orm 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.4.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     - Installation request for akeneo/pim-community-dev (locked at v1.6.22, required as ~1.6.22) -> satisfiable by akeneo/pim-community-dev[v1.6.22].
> ```

**My composer.json :**

```
{
    "name": "akeneo/pim-community-standard",
    "description": "The \"Akeneo Community Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Akeneo",
            "homepage": "http://www.akeneo.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/",
            "Context": "features/"
        },
        "psr-4": {
          "Pim\\Upgrade\\": "upgrades/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "akeneo/pim-community-dev": "~1.6.22",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/migrations": "1.2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.1.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev.git",
            "branch": "master"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
            "php app/console fos:js-routing:dump --target=web/js/routes.js"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
            "php app/console fos:js-routing:dump --target=web/js/routes.js",
            "Pim\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\ComposerScripts::copyUpgradesFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "keep-outdated": true,
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {
                "database_host": "PIM_DATABASE_HOST",
                "database_port": "PIM_DATABASE_PORT",
                "database_name": "PIM_DATABASE_NAME",
                "database_user": "PIM_DATABASE_USER",
                "database_password": "PIM_DATABASE_PASSWORD"
            }
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.7.x-dev",
            "dev-1.6": "1.6.x-dev",
            "dev-1.5": "1.5.x-dev",
            "dev-1.4": "1.4.x-dev",
            "dev-1.3": "1.3.x-dev",
            "dev-1.2": "1.2.x-dev",
            "dev-1.1": "1.1.x-dev",
            "dev-1.0": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your composer.json please?

Comment: @Med I just added it :)

Comment: @Paul Don't remove solved problems from question - existing answers will lose their context.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `"akeneo/pim-community-dev": "~1.6.22"` from `require` to `require_dev` because this breaks the minimum stability set by `"minimum-stability": "stable",`

```
"require": {
    "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.2.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.1.0",
    "akeneo/pim-community-dev": "~1.6.22"
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the same mistake with this change.

Comment: Second option, try changing your minimum stability to `dev` ?

Comment: I change to "akeneo/pim-community-dev": "1.4.8" and i have this error "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52"

Comment: This is common composer bug, read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors, hope it will helps you resolve it

Comment: This answer is incorrect - moving package to `require-dev` will never fix such errors, and `akeneo/pim-community-dev` is not a dev dependency.

Answer (score -1):

`akeneo/pim-community-dev` [has locked](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/eb410015874e3e8f79633c372b50844e731fc3f9/composer.json#L33) `doctrine/orm` to version `2.4.7`. If you use `composer require doctrine/orm` composer will try to install the newest branch of `doctrine/orm` (which is `^2.6`). You should specify constraints for `doctrine/orm` manually:

```
composer require "doctrine/orm:^2.4"
```

But this actually will not install anything, since you already have a `doctrine/orm` `v2.4.7` installed from `akeneo/pim-community-dev`. If you need a newer version of `doctrine/orm` you need to upgrade `akeneo/pim-community-dev` (or remove it completely).

---

If you want to upgrade `akeneo/pim-community-dev`, you should start from removing redundant dependencies - they're all already defined in `akeneo/pim-community-dev` package, so having them in root project will only create conflicts.

```
composer remove doctrine/migrations doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle doctrine/orm --dev
```

Then update `akeneo/pim-community-dev` package:

```
composer require akeneo/pim-community-dev --update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: beginner in this, how to upgrade akeneo/pim-community-dev ?